# Permutation of grouped objects

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Using the letters in the word **INTERMITTENT** how many 12 letter words can be formed:
a) If each arrangement begins with **T** and ends with **N**

Comment: Can you share your approach on the problem too?

Comment: Well, basically what I did is just used the formula for grouped objects: n!a!b!... where "n" is the total number of groups(including single objects), "a" in the number of members in the first group, and, etc. So, my approach was (8!)(4!)(2!)=1935360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$INTERMITTENT$ becomes $INTERMITTE$ after deleting a $T$ and a $N$. There remain $10$ letters, $2$ E's , $3$ T's , $2$ I's , $1$ N, $1$ R and $1$ M.

So, we have $\frac{10!}{2!\times 3!\times 2!\times 1!\times 1!\times 1!}=151,200$

possible arrangements.

Answer (score 2):

Make 12 blanks and fix the starting and the ending of the blanks with a T and an N, so now you have 10 vacant blanks and remaining words as:

3 T's
2 I's
2 E's
1 R,M and 1 N.

These 10 remaining can be arranged in $\frac{10!}{2!\ 2!\ 3!\ 1!\ 1!\ 1!}$ ways.
(considering repetitions)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. Now I knew what I was missing is just eliminating 2 letters from the original word.